# start phone call activity through BroadcastReceiver crashes the calling app

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() function I call the following code to make a phone call without user intervention with following code:

```
    Intent intentcall = new Intent();
    intentcall.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intentcall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber)); 
    startActivity(intentcall);
```

The above code works when placed in the onCreate function of the calling activity, but fails in the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive() function.  The BroadcastReceiver is an inner class inside the calling activity.

The following are errors:

```
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL flg=0x10000010 (has extras) } in com.ensil.vastusyscontrolunit.OutgoingReceiver@43d3d4e8 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:781) 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328) 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at android.widget.Toast.(Toast.java:105) 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:261) 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at com.ensil.vastusyscontrolunit.OutgoingReceiver.onReceive(OutgoingReceiver.java:25) 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:771) 
    11-29 15:15:40.822: E/AndroidRuntime(6354): ... 9 more
```

Comment: post your `logcat` error and how you called from `onReceive()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use your code like below code in `onReceive()`:

```
Intent intentcall = new Intent();
intentcall.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intentcall.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber)); 
intentcall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
context.startActivity(intentcall);
```

did you use Toast in your code? and how you call that because the `Toast` makes your app crashing, comment that line and try again or post that to help you.

Comment: I tried it with or without adding the following flag and still not working.    intentcall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: Yes I use it and it's in the OutgoingReceiver file that I registered.  I commented the Toast message out and it works now.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

something wrong in your

com.ensil.vastusyscontrolunit.OutgoingReceiver.onReceive

line 25 it says null pointer exception.